# jQuery Import Error With CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, canvasjs

I am working on getting the commerical version of canvasJS graphs to display on an HTML page. The trial worked like a charm. When I transition to the commercial version I had these issues with jQuery (v1.12.0) loading it.

To get the data to the canvasJS graph, I am using angular (v1.5.8) to send the data to the canvasJS graph (see below). Yet, when I load the graph, the browser give this error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'js'
```

I've checked many version of jQuery. The canvasJS team says it is compatible with jQuery 1.4.0 or higher (upto 3.2.1). Yet, when I run the `jQuery.getScript` in the controller, the server continues to respond with the error above. If this matter, I am running nodejs on the backend.

**Is there a way to solve this issue or perhaps another way to load the canvasJS script without using jQuery?**

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"
   integrity="sha256-yFU3rK1y8NfUCd/B4tLapZAy9x0pZCqLZLmFL3AWb7s="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Angular Controller

```
app.controller('chartController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

  jQuery.getScript("commercial/canvasjs.js", function(){

    $scope.chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", {
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        axisY: {
            labelFontSize: 16,
        },
        axisX: {
            labelFontSize: 16,
        },
        data: [
            {
                dataPoints: [
                { label: "apple", y: 10 },
                { label: "orange", y: 15 },
                { label: "banana", y: 25 },
                { label: "mango", y: 30 },
                { label: "grape", y: 28 }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    $scope.chart.render();

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your jQuery vendor is loaded before angular vendor library, other then that you can write bit more about your bundle process if you have one.